# How to similate download speed with bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to simulate a download speed with a bar?

Example show with a bar how long time it takes to download 5 MB with a 1 Mbyte/s connection.

I have made a bar with CSS and HTML to simulate 40%:
http://jsfiddle.net/JxfAk/3/

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var Download = 1048576
var Data = 1048576 * 5


});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="barboks"><div id="bar"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#barboks {width:200px;height:40px;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
#bar {width:50px;height:40px;background:blue;display:block;}
```

I just don't know how I should very-ate the width of the bar as the download speed of the data.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: My guess is it sounds like you want us to solve your school assignment.

Comment: Haha no I need to use this for my own site broadband site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kt6Bc/2/

HTML--

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS--

```
#container {
    position : relative;
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 25px;
    border   : 1px solid #000;
    overflow : hidden;
}
#bar {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 0;
    height     : 25px;
    background : red;
}
```

JS--

```
var ani_running = false;
$('#container').on('click', function () {
    if (ani_running == false) {
        ani_running = true;
        $('#bar').animate({ width : '500px' }, 5000, function () {
            $('#bar').animate({ width : '0px' }, 1000);
            ani_running = false;
        });
    }
});
```

This will set a div within another div and animate the inner div's width to look like a loading bar. Since the width of the parent div is `500px` we can simulate `1MB/s` by taking `5sec` to animate the width of the inner div.

Comment: I am wondering over this ISP: https://www.unotel.dk/adsl.asp on the bottom of the page there is a download speed simulator made in flash. And I have taken the time with my stopwatch. With a 5 MB connection it takes at least 9 seconds to download 5 MB I see. Is it because there is a mistake in there flash animation? So that the bar is slower then normal.

Comment: @Railsbeginner It looks like they are just trying to demonstrate the relative difference in speeds. The `5MB/s` connection is four times slower than the `20MB/s` connection.

Comment: Yes but is it strange they are making slower than it should. When they are saying it is the time it takes to download 5 MB.